# Android is not sending events to www.google-analytics.com/g/collect

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics

I need to send some (reserved) events with tagged approach with this fetch:

```
await fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-VL44251M704V&cid=fe98aeca859f9afa&sid=32f161bb-5553-4162-b6d2-ffb3fa4f4140&ul=en&uap=android&uapv=33&uamb=1&en=screen_view&seg=1&sr=1080x2186&dl=dom2&ua=dom2&dh=dom2&dp=dom2&dt=dom2&cd=dom2&ec=dom2&uid=dom2&t=pageview&an=pageview&ea=pageview&in=pageview&up.device_manufacturer=samsung&up.device_platform=android&up.app_version=3.1.15-alpha.119&up.device_platform_version=33', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors', 
        cache: 'no-cache', 
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            Host: ' www.google-analytics.com',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': 0,
        },
        body: {
            en=screen_view&ep.firebase_screen=landing
        },
    });
```

But no such events are comming into Firebase console from Android device. iOS is working fine, problem is only with Android.